# Why isn't this simple python script using openCV working?

Tags: python, opencv

So I found a [python script](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/is-there-photo-analysis-software-which-will-pre-sort-images-by-identifying-poten) that I think would be extremely useful to me. It allegedly will sort photos into "blury" or "not blurry" folders.

I'm very much a python newb, but I managed in still python 3.7, numpy, and openCV. I put the script in a folder with a bunch of .jpg images and run it by typing in the command prompt:

```
python C:\Users\myName\images\BlurDetection.py
```

When I run it though it just immediately returns:

`Done.  Processed 0 files into 0 blurred, and 0 ok.`

No error messages or anything. It just doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Here's the script.

```
#
# Sorts pictures in current directory into two subdirs, blurred and ok
#

import os
import shutil
import cv2

FOCUS_THRESHOLD = 80
BLURRED_DIR = 'blurred'
OK_DIR = 'ok'

blur_count = 0
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.jpg')]

try:
   os.makedirs(BLURRED_DIR)
   os.makedirs(OK_DIR)
except:
   pass

for infile in files:

   print('Processing file %s ...' % (infile))
   cv_image = cv2.imread(infile)

   # Covert to grayscale
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   # Compute the Laplacian of the image and then the focus
   #     measure is simply the variance of the Laplacian
   variance_of_laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()

   # If below threshold, it's blurry
   if variance_of_laplacian < FOCUS_THRESHOLD:
      shutil.move(infile, BLURRED_DIR)
      blur_count += 1
   else:
      shutil.move(infile, OK_DIR)

print('Done.  Processed %d files into %d blurred, and %d ok.' % (len(files), blur_count, len(files)-blur_count))
```

Any thoughts why it might not be working or what is wrong? Please advise.
Thanks!!

Comment: because there are no '.jpg' files in the folder you are running the script in?

Comment: There are 2587 .jpg images i the folder I am running the script in, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: are you sure they are not '.JPG' files?

Comment: Can you add print(len(files)) before try:
Also check if they are truly '.jpg' and not .Jpg .JPG. I ran the code in a folder with a jpg image and it does work for me.

Comment: Run the command `dir` in Command Prompt in `C:\Users\myName\images\` and attach to your post a subset of the printed results so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: where are you running your command from? Make sure that the images are in your WORKING DIRECTORY!

Comment: They definately have the .jpg extension and not the .Jpg or .JPG or any other extension.

Comment: @Micka - Ohhh. You're right. I found out what the working directory was, put all the images there, and now it seems to be working :) I thought that the script would look at the images in whatever folder it was in. Thanks for clearing that up!!

Comment: there probably is a command in python to get the path where the script is placed, then you could add it to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Your script and photos are here:

```
C:\Users\myName\images
```

But that is not your *working directory*, i.e. Python looks for your photos in whatever this returns to you:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

To make Python look for the files in the right folder, simply do:

```
os.chdir('C:\Users\myName\images')
```

Now it will be able to hit the files.

Answer (score 0):

If .jpg images are already present in the directory then please check for folders "blurred" and "ok" in the directory. The error could be because these two folders are already present in the listed directory. I ran this code and it worked for me but when i re-ran this code without deleting the blurred and ok folder, I got the same error.